# Timezone UTC to Europe/London +- 0 hours?

Tags: timezone-offset

I am a little confused about timezone calculations... Of course London is 1 hour ahead of UTC, but why does [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) say, that there is no difference between London and UTC???

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

London time is the same as UTC and GMT during the winter.

This is from that link:

> Places that observe daylight saving time (DST) during their respective summer periods are listed only once, at the offset for their winter (usually known as "standard") period; see their individual articles for more information.

It lists places using winter time and ignores DST.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there any source for those conversions? I'd like to have them in my SQL.